# Subsequent PDF rendering issue in iframe in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, jspdf

Using jsPDF I am generating PDF and rendering it into new browser window using iframe with following code on a button click event, this is working fine for first button click but for subsequent clicks just new windows are opened with PDF error as shown below in Chrome browser only, working fine in FF.

```js
var string = pdf.output('datauristring');
var iframe = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + string + "'></iframe>"
var x = window.open();
x.document.open();
var y = x.document.write(iframe);
x.document.close();
```

Error screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Should try this following code. This is worked for me as well in Chrome and Firefox.

```
var doc = new jsPDF()
doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10)
var string = doc.output('datauristring')
var iframe = "<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + string + "'></iframe>"
var x = window.open()
x.document.open()
x.document.write(iframe)
x.document.close()
```